# How do I print value of tk slider every time it is updated?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a tk slider in my python program and I am trying to get its value every time I move it. Program does read out the initial value of the slider, but that is all that gets read out. 
Here is my code:

```
valuelist[50, 100, 150, 200]
class MainApp(Frame):
    def valuecheck(val, self, scale):
        scalepic = scale
        print scalepic.get()
    def createControls(self):
        scalepic = Scale(self, from_=min(valuelist), to=max(valuelist), resolution = 25, orient=HORIZONTAL)
        scalepic.set(100)
        scalepic.configure(command = self.valuecheck(val, scalepic))
        scalepic.pack()
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, width = 800, height = 600)
        self.pack()
        self.createControls()
```

I tried adding this to the body of valuecheck:

```
newval = min(valueList, key=lambda x:abs(x-float(val)))
scalepic.set(newval)
print newval
```

and got rid of resolution option when defining scalepic.
I also tried passing scalepic.get() as an argument for val. 
I also tried removing val as an argument in valuecheck
What else should I try?

Comment: You are calling `valuecheck` ONCE, during initial configuration of the slider.  You need to pass a function, not the result of calling a function, as the `command=` option.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. How would I pass the value check function in this case? Also, in general, how do you call a function every time a widget is interacted with?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Button parameter “command” executed when declared?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767228/why-is-button-parameter-command-executed-when-declared)

Answer (score 0):

Don't assign the function to the `command`. Use [`lambda`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp).

```
scalepic.configure(command = lambda :self.valuecheck(scalepic))
```

But also edit your function:

```
def valuecheck(self, scale):
```

Because there is no need for `val`.

Comment: I'm assuming the Val after lambda  deals with the issue pertaining to the callback function returning something. Is that correct?

Comment: @EricLopez-Reyes There is no need for `val`. I have edited my answer.